# ansible playbook is failing with proxy error while triggering from cron tab. its working fine when triggered manually

Tags: ansible, cron, servicenow

```
The full traceback is:
```

File "/tmp/ansible_snow_record_payload_pzajzkn7/ansible_snow_record_payload.zip/ansible_collections/servicenow/servicenow/plugins/modules/snow_record.py", line 419, in main
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysnow/resource.py", line 118, in get
return self._request.get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysnow/request.py", line 114, in get
return self._get_response("GET", stream=kwargs.pop("stream", False))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pysnow/request.py", line 57, in _get_response
method, self._url, stream=use_stream, params=params, timeout=self._timeout, **kwargs
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 510, in send
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
"changed": false,
"invocation": {
"module_args": {
"attachment": null,
"auth": "basic",
"client_id": null,
"client_secret": null,
"data": {
"state": 2
},
"display_value": false,
"exclude_reference_link": false,
"host": null,
"instance": "servicenow instance name",
"log_level": "normal",
"lookup_field": "number",
"number": "INC55558",
"openid": null,
"openid_issuer": null,
"openid_scope": [
"openid"
],
"password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER",
"raise_on_empty": true,
"state": "present",
"suppress_pagination_header": false,
"table": "incident",
"token": null,
"username": "ansible"
}
},
"**msg": "Failed to update record: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='.service-now.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/now/table/incident?sysparm_query=number%3DINC1118658&sysparm_limit=10000&sysparm_offset=0&sysparm_display_value=False&sysparm_suppress_pagination_header=False&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=False&sysparm_view=&sysparm_fields= (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:860: The handshake operation timed out',)))"
}**

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Answer (score 0):

It's because cron jobs run in a non-login shell, meaning they don't evaluate all the `/etc/bash*` (and certainly not `$HOME/.bash*` files) in the same way that a login shell does

If your job requires a proxy to work, you'll need to either wrap the ansible invocation in a wrapper shell script (one which sources those initialization files, or sets the proxy variables manually), or specify the proxy environment variables in the play's [`environment:` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html)

Comment: Thanks.. @mdaniel i don't need proxy to run this job... How can I use /etc/bash in ansible ?

Comment: With the amount of details present in your question, no one can hope to help you. If your cronjob is somehow getting those environment variables, but you **don't** want them, then the same answer applies but the opposite steps: run `env -u https_proxy ansible-playbook` from cron, create a wrapper shell script, or use the `environment:` to _blank_ those variables

Comment: its working with jenkins ... without proxy .. i just used same arguments..  #cron

Comment: issue is with proxy specified in  /etc/environment/ .  removed the proxy in file. cron working fine now .. 
thanks